# Define variable in command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface

OK, the question is simple though I can't find a real working solution.

I want to be able to `define` something while invoking a specific script.

I have tried it like `php -d DEBUG_ON myscript.php` but it's not working (when testing `if (defined("DEBUG_ON")) { }` inside the script, it returns `false`)

Also tried something along the lines of `php -r ('define("DEBUG_ON",1);') myscript.php`; which doesn't work either.

So, any ideas? (Or any suggestions on how I could achieve the very same effect?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) to pass arguments from command line. Then define them accordingly in the beginning of the script.

```
if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    define('DEBUG_ON', $argv[1]);
}
```

If you put this code in the beginning of your script, it should then define DEBUG_ON to whatever you pass as argument from commandline: `php myscript.php arg1`

You can also `define($argv[1], $argv[2]);` and then use `php myscript.php DEBUG_ON 1` to define DEBUG_ON as 1.

Comment: Arghh... The site is based on CodeIgniter, running both locally and on a live server, and also making use of terminal processes a lot, so I struggled to avoid playing with `$argv` not to mess things up; though it seems like I can't avoid it for much longer...

Comment: That last edit on your original answer seems like a neat little trick! ;-)

Comment: That should prevent it from interfering with normal use.